# Android device back button is not working in worklight

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am adding functionality to device back button using phonegap

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 WL.Logger.debug("Login init");

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 }

function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert("sample1 back button clicked");
    $('#page').load("pages/samplepage1.html", function(){
        currentPage.init();

    });
}
```

When i click on back button sample1.html page it shows alert("sample1 back button clicked")
its wrking fine

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      function onDeviceReady() {

     document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 }

function onBackKeyDown() {

    alert("sample2 back button clicked");   
    $('#page').load("pages/sample2.html", function(){
        currentPage.init();

    });
};
```

When i click on backbutton on sample2.html page it was showing 
alert("sample1 back button clicked") but not showing the alert("sample2 back button clicked") . I wrote this it  in outside the currentPage.init= function() {} in js file wt is the problem ? wt i did mistake

pls post  me  if any of u know the solution 
thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask why you are not using the Worklight-provided API to override the physical back button?

See:

- [WL.App.overrideBackButton](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_app_overridebackbutton.html)
- [WL.App.resetBackButton](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_app_resetbackbutton.html)

Answer (score 1):

//add back button to go back to login page

```
  WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc);
   function backFunc(){
$('#page').load(pagesHistory.pop(), function(){
    currentPage.init();

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I you have more the one function onBackKeyDown 
the event will call the first function he finds.
you can view the function code while debugging in chrome or firefox.